# What is the impact of the LGPL license on building solutions using abp.io?

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I want to write commercial, closed-source applications using [abp.io](https://github.com/abpframework/abp).

Given that abp.io is licensed as LGPL, LGPL is primarily seen as a license for libraries, and abp.io is a framework, not a library - does that mean that any code I write on abp.io has to be licensed as LGPL and made available to the public?

Comment: What is the difference between library and framework in this context?

Comment: To me a library is a set of code that is statically or dynamically linked and can be used without any modification.

The abp.io framework is a set of code templates that are generated and are meant to be changed based on technical and functional needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the LGPL license is often used for libraries, the license text/conditions do not in any way restrict the license to only libraries. It is even possible to license an application under the LGPL license, even though in that case the additional permissions compared to the GPL license are pointless.

I don't know abp.io so I can't judge the technical feasibility (which depends on how invasive a framework is into your code), but license wise you can create a closed-source application using abp.io, as long as the recipients of the application have the right and possibility to replace abp.io with a different, compatible, version.

Comment: This is very helpful and I believe it answers my question. If I build a solution using abp.io, I could not easily remove it and replace it with a different, compatible version since I would be updating code that was generated by abp.io.